# Function Parameters written in VS Code goes to the next line

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am working on a flutter project right now.
The problem I am facing is that whenever I write any statement to a certain length.. vs code sometimes shifts the entire code of line to the next line. My word wrapping length is at 400 so I don't think I have issues there.
[In this image I am writing a function and if you see, the arguments are shifted to the next line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCOQt.png)

Comment: `dart format`'s default line-length is 80.  The word-wrap column specified by your editor does not matter; you will need to explicitly specify `--line-length` (or disable the Dart formatter).

Comment: I have deleted the line- length from settings.json as well...still no success

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code there is a setting called `Dart: Line Length` that you can set to some other value:

[image]

After you update this, formatting the code will only wrap lines that are longer than the new value.